# A weaker Hausdorff topology on $\mathbb R$ with different system of compact subsets?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the real line $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology, generated by intervals $(a,b)\subseteq{\mathbb R}$.

Do there exist a weaker Hausdorff topology on $\mathbb R$ with different (a wider) system of compact subsets?

Comment: I think you're question's very vague, so I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for, but you could probably find something useful in Counterexamples in Topology: www.amazon.com/Counterexamples-Topology-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/048668735X

Comment: Vague? What is not clear?

Comment: Define "wider," in particular.

Comment: @Cameron: If $\tau\subseteq\tau'$, where $\tau$ and $\tau'$ are topologies on a set $X$, then every $\tau'$-compact set is $\tau$-compact, and there may be $\tau$-compact sets that aren’t $\tau'$-compact. The class of $\tau$-compact sets is wider in that sense. (It’s not the term that I’d have chosen, but in context it’s reasonably clear.)

Comment: The system of compact sets with respect to the new topology must contain the old system of compsct sets (since there are no weaker Hausdorff topologies on compact sets). So if we want to find a weaker topology with different system of compact sets, this system must be wider.

Comment: Does the Sorgenfrey line satisfy this?

Comment: @ForeverMozart: No: it’s a stronger (finer) topology.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: which word is more apt instead of "wider"? (Excuse me my English.)

Comment: @Sergei: I’m not sure that there is a better single word; I’d probably either have left it at *different*, figuring that anyone likely to answer the question would understand how it had to be different, or explained in full, more or less as in my comment. I thought that the question was perfectly clear.

Comment: @Sergei: It took me a few false starts, but I finally came up with an example. Thanks for a very interesting question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\tau$ be the Euclidean topology on $\Bbb R$, and suppose that $\tau'\subseteq\tau$ is a Hausdorff topology on $\Bbb R$. Let $K$ be any $\tau$-compact subset of $\Bbb R$. Then the subspace topology on $K$ induced by $\tau$ is a compact Hausdorff topology, which means that it’s a minimal Hausdorff topology: no strictly weaker topology on $K$ is Hausdorff. Thus, $\tau'$ must induce the usual topology on $K$. In particular, $\tau'$ and $\tau$ must agree on each of the sets $[-n,n]$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.

Let $\Bbb R^*$ be the one-point compactification of $\Bbb R$, with topology $\tau^*$, and let $p$ be the point at infinity. Let

$$\tau'=\{U\in\tau:0\notin U\text{ or }U=V\cap\Bbb R\text{ for some }V\in\tau^*\text{ such that }0,p\in V\}\;.$$

This amounts to saying that every point of $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ has its usual nbhds, and $\tau'$-open nbhds of $0$ are of the form $(\leftarrow,a)\cup U\cup(b,\to)$ for some $a,b\in\Bbb R$ and $\tau$-open nbhd $U$ of $0$. It’s easy to check that $\tau'$ is still Hausdorff. It’s also strictly weaker than $\tau$: for example, $(-1,1)\notin\tau'$, since it’s not a $\tau'$-nbhd of $0$. It turns out that this isn’t quite enough to pin down the topology, because a point can have nbhds that are locally Euclidean but have ‘tails’ far away from the point.

Let $K$ be any $\tau$-closed subset of $\Bbb R$ that contains $0$, and let $\mathscr{U}$ be a $\tau'$-open cover of $K$. There is a $U_0\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $0\in U_0$. But $\Bbb R\setminus U_0$ is a bounded, $\tau$-closed subset of $\Bbb R$, so it is compact in both topologies, and therefore $K$ is $\tau'$-compact. In particular, $[0,\to)$ is a $\tau'$-compact set that is not $\tau$-compact.

**Added:** It just occurs to me that $\langle\Bbb R,\tau'\rangle$ can also be described as the space that you get when you identify $0$ and $p$ in $\Bbb R^*$. If you take the two-point compactification of $\Bbb R$, you can identify both new points with $0$ to get my example, or you can identify the point at plus infinity with $0$ and throw away the other to get bof’s example, or you can identify one of the new points with $1$ and the other with $0$ to get two more examples (depending on which way round you do make the identifications).

Answer (score 3):

In other words, you are asking for a continuous bijection from $\mathbb R$ to a Hausdorff space, which is not a homeomorphism. Let
$$S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R\times\mathbb R:(x\le1\wedge y=0)\vee(x^2+y^2=1\wedge y\gt0)\}.$$
Topologized as a subspace of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$, $S$ is is a Hausdorff space which is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$; and there is obviously a continuous bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $S$.

The weaker topology on $\mathbb R$ that you are looking for is one which makes $\mathbb R$ homeomorphic to $S$.

Comment: Thank you! Your example is similar to the one that Brian gives (visually this is like the difference between $\rho$ and 8), but he was the first who replied, so I'll accept his answer. :)